# Can't predict unsupervised forest

Tags: r

I have the following data `df` in R used to train a random forest:

```
feature1   feature2   feature3   mytarget
1          0          1          cool
0          0          1          cool
1          1          0          warm
0          1          0          warm
1          1          1          warm
```

Then, I use `df_test` to test a trained model:

```
feature1   feature2   feature3
1          0          1
0          0          1
```

This is how I try to train a random forest:

```
library(randomForest)

f <- paste('~', paste(colnames(df)[colnames(df)!="mytarget"], collapse = ' + '))

rf <- randomForest(as.formula(f), data=df, ntree=10, nodesize=10)

df_test$pr <- predict(rf, df_test, type="prob")[,2]
```

This is the error:

Error in predict.randomForest(rf, dtest, type = "prob") : 
  No forest component in the object

If I add `keep.forest=TRUE`:

```
rf <- randomForest(as.formula(f), data=df, ntree=10, nodesize=10, keep.forest=TRUE)
```

..., then I git this error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(rf, dtest, type = "prob") : 
  Can't predict unsupervised forest.
```

Why a random forest is considered as unsupervised if I have a target `mytarget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the response as well in the `formula` either with `reformulate`

```
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(reformulate(response = 'mytarget', 
      names(df)[1:3]), data = df, ntree=10, nodesize=10)
predict(rf, df_test, type="prob")[,2]
#   1   2  
# 0.3 0.3
```

or use `paste`

```
f <- paste('mytarget ~', paste(colnames(df)[colnames(df)!="mytarget"],
       collapse = ' + '))

rf <- randomForest(as.formula(f), data=df, ntree=10, nodesize=10)
predict(rf, df_test, type="prob")[,2]
#   1   2 
# 0.2 0.2
```

---

Issue is that the `terms` doesn't have the response variable when we don't provide it

```
rf$terms
#~feature1 + feature2 + feature3
#attr(,"variables")
#list(feature1, feature2, feature3)
#attr(,"factors")
#         feature1 feature2 feature3
#feature1        1        0        0
#feature2        0        1        0
#feature3        0        0        1
#attr(,"term.labels")
#[1] "feature1" "feature2" "feature3"
```

and this gets changed when it is provided

```
rf$terms
#mytarget ~ feature1 + feature2 + feature3
#attr(,"variables")
#list(mytarget, feature1, feature2, feature3)
#attr(,"factors")
#         feature1 feature2 feature3
#mytarget        0        0        0
#feature1        1        0        0
#feature2        0        1        0
#feature3        0        0        1
#attr(,"term.labels")
#[1] "feature1" "feature2" "feature3"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(feature1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), feature2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), feature3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mytarget = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("cool", "warm"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

df_test <- structure(list(feature1 = 1:0, feature2 = c(0L, 0L), feature3 = c(1L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: For the case `'mytarget ~'` I am getting an error: `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :   <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input`

Comment: @Fluxy Not able to reproduce that error for me.  I updated with the data used

Comment: My fault. It works. And this also works: `randomForest(my_target ~ ., data=df, ntree=10, nodesize=10)`